# ¿Cómo filtrar usando where en la columna 'REFERENCED_TABLE_OTHER_COLUMNS'?

Tags: php, sql

De la consulta siguiente, necesito filtrar mediante un `LIKE` los valores de la columna `'REFERENCED_TABLE_OTHER_COLUMNS'`. Pero probando con la consulta no doy con la forma de hacerlo ya que, nunca me reconoce dicha columna. Me comentó el usuario que me ayudó realizando la consulta, que podría apoyarme en php, pero no entiendo de que manera. Sea como sea mientras consiga el resultado que busco puede ser tanto en php como solo con la consulta.

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT COLUMN_NAME 'REFERENCED_TABLE_OTHER_COLUMNS',
      TABLE_SCHEMA CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA,
      TABLE_NAME REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME
      FROM information_schema.COLUMNS
  ) c1 JOIN (
    SELECT TABLE_NAME,COLUMN_NAME,
      REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME,REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME,
      CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA
      FROM information_schema.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE
      WHERE CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA='bd_libreria'
      AND TABLE_NAME='tbl_libros'  
  ) c2 USING(CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA,REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME);
```

Answer (score 1):

Yo sí que he conseguido filtrarlos con un `WHERE`, tal que así:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT COLUMN_NAME 'REFERENCED_TABLE_OTHER_COLUMNS',
      TABLE_SCHEMA CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA,
      TABLE_NAME REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME
      FROM information_schema.COLUMNS
  ) c1 JOIN (
    SELECT TABLE_NAME,COLUMN_NAME,
      REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME,REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME,
      CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA
      FROM information_schema.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE
      WHERE CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA='bd_libreria'
      AND TABLE_NAME='tbl_libros'  
  ) c2 USING(CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA,REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME)
  WHERE REFERENCED_TABLE_OTHER_COLUMNS LIKE '%id%';
```

Adjunto también el dataset en SQL para que se pueda comprobar:

```
CREATE DATABASE bd_libreria;
USE bd_libreria;
CREATE TABLE tlb_categorias(
  id_categoria int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  nombre_categoria varchar(31)
  );
CREATE TABLE tbl_libros(
  id_libro int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  nombre_libro varchar(127),
  precio_libro float,
  id_categoria int,
  FOREIGN KEY(id_categoria) REFERENCES tlb_categorias(id_categoria)
  );
```

Sería interesante detallar el caso de uso con lo que esperas obtener y para qué vas a usarlo, para que quede más claro qué necesitas.